# Please fix my formula for Microsoft excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've Tried this formula `={(D3+D4+D5)-4}/8-F3-F4`

But the answer keeps coming up one more than is truly accurate

What I need to have my equation calculate is... (Cell Values - Actual Data)
The sum of cells: D3(3.5),D4(24.0),D5(3.75)
The sum needs to have 4 Taken off it (27.25)
That value needs to be Divided By 8 (3.40625)
Then I want Cells F3(0.00) and F4(3.0)
Subtracted from it...

IF Possible...  Rounded to the closest whole number

Doing the Calculation Manually is obviously not my issue - But my Spreadsheet has Multiple Similar Calculations - And I was hoping to have/use a Formula to work them out for me...

Comment: Better you share sample data along with expected result, will help us to test data and fit it !!

Answer (score 2):

The inner brackets are useless as you only subtract by 4 afterwards.

If you want to round, well use the function "round". If you want the closest full number, then round with ";0" at the end of the function. Besides that, your formula looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=ROUND(((D3+D4+D5-4)/8)-F3-F4,0)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't do Excel so idk their syntax, but brackets are your friend..

(((D3+D4+D5)-4)/8)-F3-F4 would remove ambiguity, even though it's slight overkill.
Maths operators will tend to do multiplication & division first; humans tend to do it in the order they read it [unless they're mathematicians;)